# Survival Analysis - Relationship between CDF and survival function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, survival

I am trying to teach myself survival analysis and I followed this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cy_99CiXhU8).

The video states that given:

$ F_x(t) = \Pr[T_x \leq t ]$ is the future probability of the life for a person who has reached $x$ years of age (aka c.d.f.)

and

$S_x(t) = \Pr[T_x > t ] = 1 - F_x(t)$ is the is the probability that a person of age $x$ will be alive for more than $t$ years (aka survival function).

The probability of someone $x$ years old dying in the next $t$ years is:

$
F_x(t) = \Pr[T_x \leq x + t | T_x > t] (Eq.1)
$

To me, it makes sense to think of this as the intersection of all those who will die at $x+t$ and who survived up until $T_x>t$. **(1. Is this the correct intuition for this?)**

The video goes on to state that we "rewrite the function (Eq.1) given that P(A) intersection P(B)" as the following:

$
F_x(t) = \frac{F(x + t)- F(x)}{P(T_x>x)} = F_x(t) = \frac{F(x + t)- F(x)}{S(x)} (Eq.2)
$

My understanding of $P(A)$ intersection $P(B)$ is that  $P(A\cap B) = P(A|B)P(B)$

If, from $Eq.1$ if I let $P(A) = T_x \leq x + t$ and $P(B) = T_x > t$ then the resulting equation would be:

$P(A\cap B) = P(A|B)P(B) = [(T_x \leq x + t)|(T_x > t)](T \leq x + t)$

I feel like I am not doing this correctly. **2. How does $S_x(t)$ end up in the denominator in Eq.2?**

I also have *Survival Data: Extending the Cox Model* by Therneau and Grambsch as a resource but they gloss over where the equations come from. I feel like this is leading up to the hazard function, but I want to make sure I understand what he going on before considering limits.

**EDIT:**

I don't think my question is clear enough. What I meant by "How does $S_x(t)$ end up in the denominator in Eq.2". I meant, how do we go from

$F_x(t) = \Pr[T_x \leq x +t|T_x >t]$ to $\frac{F(x+t)-F(x)}{P(T_x>x)}$

I am not sure how, algebraically, we get $T_x >t$ in the denominator

Comment: $F_x(t) = \Pr[T_x \leq t ]$ vs $F_x(t) = \Pr[T_x \leq x + t | T_x > t]$

Comment: I believe I understand what you are saying - in my equations the subscript, $x$ in $T_x$ is misleading. Correct?

Comment: I do not know what $F_x(t)$ is because you have two $F_x(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Derivation: For $0 < x < x+t,$ we have

$$F_x(t) = P(T \le x+t\,|\, T > x) = \frac{P(T \le x+t,\, T > x)}{P(T > x)} \\
= \frac{P(x<T\le x+t)}{P(T > x)} = \frac{F(x+t) - F(x)}{S(x)},$$
where $F(y) = P(T\le y)$ and $S(y) = P(T > y) = 1 - F(y).$

Comment: I don't think my question is clear enough. What I meant by "How does $S_x(t)$ end up in the denominator in Eq.2". I meant, how do we go from  $F_x(t) to \Pr[T_x \leq x +t|T_x >t] = \frac{F(x+t)-F(x)}{P(T_x>x)}$

Comment: The sentence "The probability of someone $x$ years old dying in the next $t$ years is:
$F_x(t) = \Pr[T_x \leq x + t | T_x > t].$" makes no sense to me. The words suppose that someone is alive at time $x,$ so in my answer I changed the conditioning event to $\{T > x\}.$ That may not be exactly what you intended, but at least it makes some sense to me.

Comment: I believe I understand what you are saying - in my equations the subscript, $x$ in $T_x$ is misleading. Correct? (Also, I don't mind you being blunt, I would rather get this right!)

Comment: I think you need to read the original text carefully and make sure you are asking what you intended to ask. Perhaps give a few steps in the derivation and show where your trouble lies.

Comment: Thanks for your honesty, I will spend some more time with Therneau and Grambsch to ensure I am asking the right question.